# Converting circular structure to JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am getting it from database I want to format this data but I am getting below error

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

    --> starting at object with constructor 'NativeConnection'

    |     property 'base' -> object with constructor 'Mongoose'

    |     property 'connections' -> object with constructor 'Array'

    --- index 0 closes the circle

    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)

    at formatReportOutput (E:\Application\routes\data.js:97:50)
```

Below is my data getting it from database

```
var routput = [{

        "_id" : ObjectId("59920689253dfa0544f26b93"),
        "INumber" : "535264",
        "IID" : "25544825",
        "DateReceived" : ISODate("2017-08-14T20:22:33.350Z"),

    }]
```

My code :
Below is my code to differentiate header and value and format value.
Format value means
mongodb id ,date

Expected output:

Headers : _id,INumber,IID,DateReceived

values:59920689253dfa0544f26b93,535264,25544825,2017-08-14

when i pass any data automatically it should display in table(ng-table(angularjs)) which means no need to hard code headers what ever we pass it should display .

please help me with this.

Comment: adding code responsible for database connection as well as printing the output of formatOutput function  would help understanding the issue

Comment: i already given database(mongodb) output(routput )

Comment: you gave an error description, not the code with the call which triggered the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the document retrieved from mongo to a plain javascript object before calling formatOutput or use lean() in your query.

Assuming routput comes from a mongoose query, formatOutput might work as expected if you call .lean() on the query or .toObject() on the array instances prior to passing it to the function.

So, something like this:

```
var routput = await Model.find().lean();
var header ="Yes";
formatOutput(routput, header);
```

Or this:

```
var routput = await Model.find();
var header ="Yes";
formatOutput(routput.map(x => x.toObject()), header);
```

Should be sufficient.

**References:**

- https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject
- https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html

Comment: Can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you didn't use `await` with mongoose method. I forgot to add await and then that error occur:

```
 const indexUsers = async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            const users = await db.User.find();
            return res.status(200).json(users);
        } catch (err) {
            next(err);
        }
    };
```

Comment: This fix the problem. :)

Comment: This was the issue for me.
I didn't use  `await`